# Call to undefined method My_email::from()

Tags: php

I have a problem creating a test library to send email. This is my code:

```
class My_email {

    public function my_send_mail() {

        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->library('email');

        $CI->email->from('xxx@xxx.com', 'Sender name');
        $CI->email->to('yyy@yyy.com');
        $CI->email->subject('Test');
        $CI->email->message('Testing');

        return $CI->email->send();

    }
 }
```

I get the error:

```
Call to undefined method My_email::from()
```

Comment: Have you **read** the error message?

Comment: We don't like this type of questions ("This broke. Repair it for me") here on Stack Exchange network. Please show more effort while debugging next time.

Answer (score 2):

The error appeared for you so you can read it and fix the problem. **Read** the error you get, that's why it's there:

Call to **undefined** method

You have to define it before you use it, right in your `My_Email` class

Comment: I'm trying to use a method of $CI->email class, not a method of my class.

Comment: Then why are you calling it like it's from this class? I think my answer is what you were trying to do, is it not?

Comment: @user1039779: but $CI->email is an instance of My_email

Answer (score 0):

The method is not defined, if it's a method from another class and you want to use it with this class use `extends email` or what ever it is you want.

This will make the class inherit everything from the extended class.

Actually, no, firstly, your method from isn't even a problem, but then your trying to call methods and a class that we know nothing about....

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm new to codeigniter and perhaps this is a common question for beginners. I imagine it was possible to call a method of a class loaded from the instance of CI.

Comment: Down a bit on this page look at extending native classes or something like that http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: Wow, I just noticed that your comment was translated, thats awesome.